# Git: Restore uncommited changes lost after checkout

Tags: git

I was working on my branch and I forgot to commit my changes. Then I switched to a master branch and pulled changes from the repo. After that I went back to my branch and merged the changes from master.
I tried looking for some ways to undo the changes, like [this site](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things) but nothing worked.

Here's the commands I ran:

```
(on branch new)
git add -A
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout new
git merge master
```

So I forgot to commit after adding all files and now all my changes are lost. Is there a way to bring it back?

`git reflog` gives me:

```
1b131cc HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from new to new
1b131cc HEAD@{2}: merge master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
1b68f12 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to new
481a3d8 HEAD@{4}: pull: Fast-forward
d036eda HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from new to master
```

`git fsck --lost-found` gives me:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (7099/7099), done.
dangling blob 318983dc9be70b96795f20ddc30da34506a90686
dangling blob fb92b205dbeeeb507b57dac1ef71676cda81393f
dangling blob 459e993441c9d87620a16acf13ea775fbf2995d2
dangling blob 2927b0f2104b6cf81e70cac33059ca3170555347
dangling blob d82971111c7b858e3ae9444d1f63ac9dfb864c49
dangling commit 65b0e95ec2b07837b921d032f7233abbe58e67eb
dangling commit 8f31e7b43d82894e825d73b3e57c2a1cd93b9ec2
dangling commit f5b13ac3cad384c6752081a82114647f879083df
dangling blob 3dccfdeee2d715045a8063cf92f89c0c70dbb96c
dangling commit 8cd2e7c0d89389dcac3f0cc0644874e06675128f
dangling commit 2fd6e1a36046432173c8aec3f3e50cb4182fdabb
dangling blob b9dc20c047ca16043a3eb6899284b86d4cdcc70b
dangling blob 11deb3d56d8902578f78f2c7477662bac1d378bd
dangling commit ea66df6e6d273360f0401bab69d2f4021daa3d49
dangling commit b16afa88716265f3aa4df1d40bd0a8471a631d51
dangling blob 207440e8625330fd26925f0c15485caea2aa723d
dangling blob b8f7e70d326474263b7910a16a9e18e13efbfafb
dangling blob 93793d9b405aff5117bd91cfe40008c583278756
```

Comment: what do you see when you run git reflog, what do you see when you run git fsck --lost-found?

Comment: @Quantico edited question to include output of these commands.

Comment: Sorry, don't see anything. Maybe someone else will have an idea.

Comment: Stupid question, but I assume you're sure your changes are lost? I've just tried to repeat the steps as you describe them, and I can't find any combination that doesn't just leave my uncommitted changes still ready to be committed. Presumably they're not in the 'Changes to be committed' section when you run `git status`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a step. I assume that @ git add -A you had some work done.

```
(on branch new)
git add -A
git checkout master
```

At this point you would see this message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        bla.file
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

At this step you made either a git stash, git reset(here you lost your work if you did it with --hard) or git commit (if you do not have your changed you did git stash otherwise you would see your changes that are supposed to be lost).

Two ways are leading to lost work in this case.

1. Not saved files
2. git reset --hard

If you committed your changes you will find them in the branch you committed them. If you stashed them you will find the in the stash list.